# Excel Vlookup Between Two Dates With Returning Multiple Data

Tags: excel, search, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

Basicly i have a list of information and i need to be able to enter a start data in one cell and a end date in a different cell and then return all the dates between them.

```
eg.

input       input
1/1/14      2/2/14

Return
Date      Name
14/1/14    bob
17/1/14    bob2
20/1/14    bob3
```

Dont no if you can do this with vlookup or index and match but any help would be good

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is an IF(AND) statement.

```
=IF(AND(G6>E6,G6<F6),TRUE)
```

Where G6 is the date you are checking, and E6 and F6 hold the date range.  TRUE can be replaced with any value, including a reference to a different cell.

Comment: then could i do a vlookup for all the true values?

Comment: I would suggest setting the values from your formula, then run a VLOOKUP on THAT.  Far less complex than trying to nest the whole thing.

Comment: would you be able so show me how that formual look?

Comment: You don't need a VLOOKUP at all.  If I understand what you mean...  You have a name field associated with the date, right?  In the formula I provided, you can renturn the name, rather than TRUE.  You can also add a secondary column with the same forumula that returns the date in question.  Yes, you'll have to run this vertically cross them all.  But you'll have the answers you need.